# Angular 2 in laravel doesn't works

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-elixir

so I followed [this tutorial](https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-and-angular-2-beta-setup/)  and at the end I got this error

`system.src.js:1049 GET http://localhost:8000/boot.js 404 (Not Found)`

it's my gulpfile :

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

var elixirTypscript = require('elixir-typescript');

elixir(function(mix) {
   mix.sass('app.scss');

mix.copy('node_modules/angular2', 'public/angular2');
mix.copy('node_modules/rxjs', 'public/rxjs');
mix.copy('node_modules/systemjs', 'public/systemjs');
mix.copy('node_modules/es6-promise', 'public/es6-promise');
mix.copy('node_modules/es6-shim', 'public/es6-shim');
mix.copy('node_modules/zone.js', 'public/zone.js');

mix.typescript(
    [
        'app.component.ts',
        'boot.ts'
    ],
    'public/',
    {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    }
);

});
```

it's my app.component.ts :

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

and it's my boot:

```
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>

import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

and finally it's my blade view I placed these lines in head tag if it matters (I really don't know anymore... )

```
 <script src="es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
            "defaultJSExtensions": true,
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });

        System.import('boot')
                .then(nPull, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

Comment: In your gulp file change 'public' to 'public/boot.js'

Comment: @tam didn't work :(

Comment: Are you familiar with Typescript, or just using it because the tutorial says so? This could be a ton easier.

Comment: @ohgodwhy well there is another tutorial (god I see lots of tutorials) that uses typescript so I have to import it with ts

Comment: When you run gulp, are there any errors there? Does it show that the boot.js is being created, and if so is it being created in the public folder?

Comment: @tam it runs without errors and it doesn't show that the boot.is has been created

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your files .ts is in  "resources/assets/typescript/" and your call on the page have the full path like "app/typescript/.

after call Gulp it will create "app/typescript/" with the files in your "resources/assets/typescript/"

```
System.import('app/typescript/boot').catch(console.log.bind(console))
```

on my setup works fine after this adjusts.